# Efficient way to perform grouping without using aggregate SOQL queries

Tags: soql, bestpractice, aggregate, multi-currency

I have an aggregate query that groups my custom object records by 4-5 fields and then returns a sum of currency fields in each grouping. I have multicurrency enabled so this sum of the currency field is being returned in USD. :( Trying to convert the results back into CAD is causing issues with precision and rounding.

So I felt its best if I can do my own aggregation. So I have changed my query to return a list of the records and so far the best solution I found is to iterate repeatedly through my list and create groups and sum up their amounts but this is proving to be inefficient.

Can someone please suggest perhaps a better and efficient solution where we can acheive grouping NON Agrregate SOQL results. I know that almost everyone would prefer to use Aggregate queries to perform grouping but I am hoping someone had the need to do a similar thing. 
Thanks.

Comment: Share some code? There's no reason why aggregating data yourself should be inefficient if you're using the correct code constructs.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using "convertCurrency(field)" in your SELECT to retrieve field in the user's currency :
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_currency_fields.htm